# HTML5 data elements avoid 0

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an HTML5 web app which uses custom data- attributes. So, see the following example:

```
<li><a href="#" class="line" data-line="02">Platform 9 3/4</a></li>
```

Doing this:

```
console.log($(this).jqmData('line'));
```

On a click event over that element, outputs 2, but not 02. This causes major issues since data is stored as strings and not numbers. It may be 'A1' or '55'.

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: What is `.jqmData()`? Have you tried `.data()`? jQuery parses HTML5 data attributes as well since... some version. In the worst case you can always use `.attr('data-line')`.

Comment: .jqmData() is the equivalent of data in jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$(this).attr('data-line')` returns the value of "02". Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/ZkDgZ/

Answer (score 2):

Use plain JavaScript.

```
// elem: variable containing element
elem.getAttribute("data-line");
```

This returns `02` as a string, which is what you need.